# Store codeigniter libraries in sub folders

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible to store libraries in sub folders in codeigniter? For example would something like this work?

```
-libraries
---sub_folder1
-----someClass.php
---sub_filder2
-----someClass2.php
```

If it does how should I load and use these libraries?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Library files can be stored in subdirectories within the main "libraries" folder, or within your personal application/libraries folder. To load a file located in a subdirectory, simply include the path, relative to the "libraries" folder. For example, if you have file located at:

```
libraries/flavors/chocolate.php
```

You will load it using:

```
$this->load->library('flavors/chocolate');
```

You may nest the file in as many subdirectories as you want.

Explained on the loader class manual page

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: Can I do also the same thing with config files too ? for instance: `$this->load->config('sub_folder/my_config.php');`

Comment: after loading a library how can I  use this type of library. is it this way?  `$this->flavors/chocolate'->common_date(); `

Comment: It's so long ago since I've used this but if I recall correctly you can do `$this->chocolate->common_date()`. If not, you can alias the class when you load it `$this->load->library('flavors/chocolate', '', 'chocolateflavor'); $this->chocolateflavor->common_date()`

Comment: How to call a method inside chocolate.php from the controller as it is nested ? I/m getting error "Message: Call to a member function method_name() on a non-object"